# App Closes when trying to load from Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from a firestore DB but every time I run the method the app crashes. I have had a look at the logcat debugger but I'm not sure what it all means.

If I comment the method `getAsessList()`, the layout loads and all. But with it uncommented, the app crashes so I'm assuming the problem lies in there.

Here is the activity code:

```
package com.version.crt.markbuddy;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.version.crt.markbuddy.model.Assessment; 
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class EditImportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int selected_position = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @BindView(R.id.friend_list)
    RecyclerView friendList;

    @BindView(R.id.txt1)
    TextView txt1;

    @BindView(R.id.btn1)
    Button btn1;


    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_import);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        init();
        getAsessList();
    }

    private void init(){
        linearLayoutManager = new     LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,     false);
        friendList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void getAsessList(){
        Query query = db.collection("test");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Assessment> response = new     FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Assessment>()
                .setQuery(query, Assessment.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, AssHolder>    (response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(AssHolder holder, int position,     Assessment model) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.textView_title.setText(model.getDesc());
                holder.textView_date.setText(model.getDate());
                holder.textView_time.setText(model.getTime());
                holder.textView_weighting.setText(model.getWeight());

                if (selected_position == position) {

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }


                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
                    txt1.setText(model.getDesc());
                    // Updating old as well as new positions

                    notifyItemChanged(selected_position);
                    selected_position = position;
                    notifyItemChanged(selected_position);

                    Snackbar.make(friendList, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                });


            }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AssHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup group, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_tape1, group, false);

            return new AssHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class AssHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.textView_title)
    TextView textView_title;
    @BindView(R.id.textView_date)
    TextView textView_date;
    @BindView(R.id.textView_time)
    TextView textView_time;
    @BindView(R.id.textView_weighting)
    TextView textView_weighting;

    AssHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

and the debuglog:

[image: debug]

What am I missing or doing wrong

Grades 
Module: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.version.crt.markbuddy"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:3.0.2'
    implementation     'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'

    //anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    //groupie
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.0.3'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    //kotlin annotation processor
    kotlin {

        experimental {

            coroutines "enable"

        }

        }
    androidExtensions {

        experimental = true

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Project:Mark buddy

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.60'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.4'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please add the content of your both `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @AlexMamo Added for you. The problem is the `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding the [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library, to solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
```

And also:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```